# Cloud Function v2 cors set to true but still get error The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is ''

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

My goal is to create a session cookie and return it in the Response Header's Set-Cookie.

The problem:

1. `httpsCallable` do not send the `idToken` nor the `csrfToken`, so I use `httpClient`.
2. `response.cookies?.csrfToken` is undefined, so I use `{ withCredentials: true }` in the Angular app. If I set `{ withCredentials: true }`, then I will get error below. Adding `{ cors: true }` or `response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');` in the cloud function code, don't work.

When I sent the request through Angular, I will not see the Response Header's `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`. But when I send request directly to the cloud function, I get the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`.

> localhost/:1  Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/mereka-io-staging/us-central1/sessionCookie-sessionLogin' from origin 'http://localhost:4203' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

projects/auth/src/app/feat/auth/data/datasources/post-session-login-function-data-source/post-session-login-function-data-source.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PostSessionLoginResponseModel } from '../../models/post-session-login-function/post-session-login-function-response.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { lastValueFrom, take } from 'rxjs';

/* Semantic Versioning
 * released: true
 */
@Injectable()
export class PostSessionLoginFunctionDataSourceService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  async post(idToken: string, csrfToken: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const request$ = this.httpClient
      .post(
        'http://127.0.0.1:5001/<project-name>/us-central1/sessionCookie-sessionLogin',
        {
          idToken: idToken,
          csrfToken: csrfToken,
        },
        {
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      )
      .pipe(take(1));

    try {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
      const result = await lastValueFrom<PostSessionLoginResponseModel>(
        request$
      );
      return true;
    } catch {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

functions/feat/session-cookie/controllers/session-login/session-login.controller.ts

```
import { onRequest } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https';
import { auth } from '../../../../const/firebase-admin/firebase-admin.const';
import { SessionCookieOptions } from 'firebase-admin/auth';
import { CookieOptions } from 'express';
import * as logger from 'firebase-functions/logger';

export const sessionLogin = onRequest(
  { cors: true },
  async (request, response) => {
    response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'localhost:4203');
    response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');

    if (request.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      // Send response to OPTIONS requests
      response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE');
      response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Bearer, Content-Type');
      response.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
      response.status(204).send('');
    }

    const idToken = request.body.idToken;
    const csrfToken = request.body.csrfToken;

    // Guard against CSRF attacks.
    if (!request.cookies || csrfToken !== request.cookies?.csrfToken) {
      response.status(401).send({ status: 'Unauthorized' });
      return;
    }

    const decodedIdToken = await auth.verifyIdToken(idToken);

    // we are enforcing that the user signed in in the last 5 minutes.
    const now = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    const withinFiveMinutes = now - decodedIdToken.auth_time < 5 * 60;
    if (!withinFiveMinutes) {
      response.status(401).send({ status: 'Unauthorized' });
      return;
    }

    // Set session expiration to 5 days.
    const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 5 * 1000;
    const sessionCookieOptions: SessionCookieOptions = {
      expiresIn: expiresIn,
    };

    const sessionCookie = await auth.createSessionCookie(
      idToken,
      sessionCookieOptions
    );

    const cookieOptions: CookieOptions = {
      maxAge: expiresIn,
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true,
    };

    response.cookie('__session', sessionCookie, cookieOptions);
    response.status(200).send({ status: 'OK' });
  }
);
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are adding `cors: true` and also trying to work the cors headers yourself.  Pick one or the other, but not both.  [Functions v2 documentation on cors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?gen=2nd#configuring_cors_cross-origin_resource_sharing) suggests you just add the config, and that's all.

Comment: @DougStevenson sorry, was trying to troubleshoot. Adding `cors: true` will modify `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin` which solves the 1st problem. Right now I am trying to solve the `Allow-Control-Allow-Credentials` which failed. My peer suggested to use Express in Cloud Function, I intend to explore that next week.

Comment: Maybe you'd like to edit the question to be more clear what the problem is, and the minimal code that reproduces it?